# C++ calling a C++ library function but the wrong function is executed

Tags: android, c++, linker, clang

I am calling a library class's functions from my app and a different function in the same class is being executed. This is a very large program with the android c# calling c++ functions. That part is working fine. The c++ code is calling into a dynamic (*.so) library but the wrong function is being executed.
Working in VS2019, Clang 5.0 toolset for both the library code and the app's code. The library source code is from a third party but ported and compiled by me. The same code works fine in windows.
The following is a condensation of the code in question.

Include file contents shared by library and app code:

*assume the items pointed to (ie FileHeader etc ) are declared in an include file.*

```
namespace nsLibraryNameSpc
{
    class Iitems
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Iitems(void) {};
        virtual  int GetAnItem( int instance, unsigned itemID, char *fieldName ) = 0;
    };  
    class Itable
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Itable(void) {};
        virtual int GetBaseInfo( BaseInfo *pBI ) = 0;
        virtual int GetTablePtr( MainTableContents *pMTC ) = 0;
    };  
    class Imethods
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Imethods(void) {};
        virtual int StartMethod( unsigned methodNumber ) = 0;
        virtual int CancelMethod( unsigned methodNumber ) = 0;
    };  
    class Imyclass : public Iitems, public Itable, Imethods
    {
        public:
        Imyclass( void ) {};
        virtual ~Imyclass(void) {};
        
        virtual void GetFileHeader( FileHeader** pFh ) = 0;
        virtual  int AddFileHeader( const char* fileNm, const FileHeader * pFh ) = 0;
        virtual void *testCall02( void *p1, void *p2 ) = 0;
        virtual void *testCall01( void ) = 0;
    };
}
```

The Library source code:

*assume the methods in classes Iitems, Itable and Imethods exist in the library.*

*assume LOG(char *fmt,...) will log the string to a file.*

MyClass.cpp

```
class MyClass : public Imyclass
{
private:
    FileHeader *pHeader;
    unsigned activeMethod;
    
public:
        MyClass( int instance )
        {
            pHeader = 0;
            activeMethod = 0;
        }       
        virtual ~MyClass() 
        {
            if (pHeader != 0)
                delete pHeader;
        }       
        virtual void GetFileHeader( FileHeader** pFh )
        {
            LOG("Inside GetFileHeader\n");
            if (pFh != 0)
                *pFh = pHeader;
            return;
        }       
        virtual  int AddFileHeader( const char* fileNm, const FileHeader * pFh )
        {       
            LOG("Inside AddFileHeader\n");
            //if the file exists then load the file header else return -1;
            LOG("AddFileHeader calling testCall01\n");
            testCall01();
            LOG("Exiting AddFileHeader\n");
            return 0;       
        }       
        virtual void *testCall01( void ) 
        {
            LOG("Inside testCall01\n");
            return 0;
        }       
        virtual void *testCall02( void *p1, void *p2 )
        {
            LOG("Inside testCall02\n");
            return 0;
        }       
        int GetBaseInfo( BaseInfo *pBI )
        {
            // some work
            return 0;
        }
        int GetTablePtr( MainTableContents *pMTC )
        {
            // some work
            return 0;
        }               
        int StartMethod( unsigned methodNumber )
        {
            // some work
            return 0;
        }
        int CancelMethod( unsigned methodNumber )
        {
            // some work
            return 0;
        }       
        int GetAnItem( int instance, unsigned itemID, char *fieldName )
        {
            // some work
            return 0;
        }
}

static int instCntr = 0;

Imyclass *makeMyClass(void)
{
    Imyclass * pRet = (Imyclass *) new MyClass(++instClass);
    return pRet;
}
```

Android app's C++ code:

```
int testLibraryCalls(void)
{
    Imyclass *pclass = makeMyClass();
    
    LOG("In testLibraryCalls\n");
    pclass->testCall02( (void*)0, (void*)0 );
    LOG("testCall02 finished\n");
    pclass->testCall01();
    LOG("testCall01 finished\n");
    pclass->GetFileHeader(0);
    LOG("GetFileHeader finished\n");
    AddFileHeader( (void*)0, (void*)0 );
    LOG("AddFileHeader finished\n");
}
```

The log file shows:

```
In testLibraryCalls
Inside AddFileHeader
AddFileHeader calling testCall01
Inside testCall01
Exiting AddFileHeader
testCall02 finished
Inside testCall02
testCall01 finished
GetFileHeader finished
Inside GetFileHeader
AddFileHeader finished
```

So calling testCall02 is executing AddFileHeader,

AddFileHeader is calling testCall01 (in the same class from the library code) correctly.

Calling testCall01 from the app executes testCall02 in the library.

Calling GetFileHeader from the app either doesn't execute or calls something without a LOG statement.

Calling AddFileHeader executes GetFileHeader in the library.

I have verified there is only one .so file on this pc with the offending functions listed in the nm output.

To me, this looks like a library loader failure but I can't believe that. Any ideas about what's wrong or how to determine the root cause would be very useful.

===============================================================

Update: I made this top level dynamic library into a static library (*.a) and linked it into the main app. No change. Calls still went to the same wrong functions. So runtime linking is not part of the problem.

Comment: Avoid casting: `(Imyclass *) new MyClass(++instClass);`. `(Imyclass *)` is unneeded here (and can hide issue in case of coding error).

Comment: Jarod42 - typo, sorry. Edited.

Comment: using `override` is still preferable though.

Comment: Your `LOG` function might be reordering output in some weird way. Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By using the syntax (from stackoverflow):

```
void ( Imyclass::* pHeader)(FileHeader* pFileHeader) = &Imyclass::GetFileHeader;
void* pGetFileHeader = (void*&)pHeader;
LOG("==== %p from virtual GetFileHeader", pGetFileHeader);

int ( Imyclass::* pFunc)(const char *, const FileHeader ) = &Imyclass::AddFileHeader;
void* pAddHeader = (void*&)pFunc;
LOG("==== %p from virtual AddFileHeader", pAddHeader);
// these returned an offset into the class's virtual function table
```

and inserting it in the Library's makeMyClass before it returned and inserting a similar pair
after makeMyClass returned to the app from the library, I found that the virtual
function table in the app was 4 bytes (one pointer) off.

It turns out that I had left out a virtual function in the Iitems class example.
I left it out because it was inside a #ifdef that was not defined in the app.

It was defined in the library.

```
class Iitems
{
public:
    virtual ~Iitems(void) {};
    virtual  int GetAnItem( int instance, unsigned itemID, char *fieldName ) = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void DisplayString(char* str);
#endif
};
```

Defining _DEBUG in the app solved the issue.